# PyQt5: Want to start a specific subprocess with a button click

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

One day old in terms of experience with PyQT, I followed sample code [HERE](http://codeprogress.com/python/libraries/pyqt/showPyQTExample.php?index=408&key=QTextEditRedStdOutput&version=5) to do this, but I am clueless as to how I could separate the start download part from the start GUI part, so that I can instead start that when I press the OK (startBtn)button. Also, know the command I do doesn't do anything but give you an error, but I know that works.
Any help appreciated!

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QMainWindow, QAction, qApp, QDesktopWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QProcess
import sys


class GUI(QProcess):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Create an instance variable here (of type QTextEdit)
        startBtn = QPushButton('OK')
        stopBtn = QPushButton('Cancel')

        #startBtn.clicked.connect()
        stopBtn.clicked.connect(qApp.exit)

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(startBtn)
        self.hbox.addWidget(stopBtn)
        self.edit = QTextEdit()

        self.edit.setWindowTitle("QTextEdit Standard Output Redirection")

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)

        #setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.central=QWidget()

        #self.vbox.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.central.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.central.show()

    def readStdOutput(self):
        self.edit.append(str(self.readAllStandardOutput()))




def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qProcess = GUI()

    qProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels);
    qProcess.start("youtube-dl")
    qProcess.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(qProcess.readStdOutput);

    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

2 notes:

1. If you also know how to disable the OK button when you press it, until the process is finished, then I'd love to know.
2. Not all imports are used, but I can clean that later. PyCharm show which is used and not. Cleanup is for later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you ask you have to have some considerations:

- `youtube-dl` requires parameters, like the url, for this I have placed a `QLineEdit`.
- To know when the process starts and ends, we use the signal: `stateChanged(newState)`

**Complete code:**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QTextEdit, QLabel, QLineEdit


class GUI(QProcess):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        # Create an instance variable here (of type QTextEdit)
        self.startBtn = QPushButton('OK')
        self.stopBtn = QPushButton('Cancel')

        self.hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox.addStretch(1)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.startBtn)
        self.hbox.addWidget(self.stopBtn)

        self.label = QLabel("Url: ")
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()

        self.lineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.EnableStart)

        self.hbox2 = QHBoxLayout()
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.label)
        self.hbox2.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        self.edit = QTextEdit()
        self.edit.setWindowTitle("QTextEdit Standard Output Redirection")

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addStretch(1)

        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox2)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.edit)
        self.vbox.addLayout(self.hbox)

        self.central = QWidget()

        self.central.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.central.show()

        self.startBtn.clicked.connect(self.startDownload)
        self.stopBtn.clicked.connect(self.kill)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.slotChanged)

        self.EnableStart()

    def slotChanged(self, newState):
        if newState == QProcess.NotRunning:
            self.startBtn.setDisabled(False)
        elif newState == QProcess.Running:
            self.startBtn.setDisabled(True)

    def startDownload(self):
        self.start("youtube-dl", [self.lineEdit.text()])

    def readStdOutput(self):
        self.edit.append(str(self.readAllStandardOutput()))

    def EnableStart(self):
        self.startBtn.setDisabled(self.lineEdit.text() == "")


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    qProcess = GUI()

    qProcess.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess.MergedChannels)
    qProcess.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(qProcess.readStdOutput)

    return app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this will help out a ton! This was the hard part for me. I use Youtube-dl with a .txt file that i update manually, and a few other paramterter, that i have, but didn't include. Now i'm going to be learning to change/add parameters with the GUI.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just had to google how to do that first... -.- I'm new to the site... it was so obvious...